# Shuffle/Randomize Questions from an Array with no Repetition (SWIFT)

Tags: arrays, swift, random, shuffle, non-repetitive

I've been browsing for several hours to find the right answer but seems like I can't apply it properly to my own code.
Most of the time, the answers given on stackoverflow for this problem are with Strings & Int examples and I'm struggling with the Question Type.
I'm just starting on Xcode & Swift and managed so far to make a Quiz App that works perfectly fine.
I've used shuffle but I can't find the rest of the code not to repeat questions previously asked.
**What I exactly want to do** : I have 7 questions for now, I want those to be asked ONCE in different orders anytime someone wants to play the Quiz.

I've got two classes in 2 other swift files.

This is my QuestionBank type with 7 questions all completed properly:

```
class QuestionBank {
var list = [Question]()


    init () {
        list.append(Question(questionNumber: 0, image: "a", questionText: "a", choiceA: "a", choiceB: "a", choiceC: "a", choiceD: "a", answer: 1))
```

And this is my Question class :

```
}
class Question {

    let number : Int
    let questionImage: String
    let question: String
    let optionA: String
    let optionB: String
    let optionC: String
    let optionD: String
    let correctAnswer: Int


    init(questionNumber: Int, image: String, questionText: String, choiceA: String, choiceB: String, choiceC: String, choiceD: String, answer: Int) {

        number = questionNumber
        questionImage = image
        question = questionText
        optionA = choiceA
        optionB = choiceB
        optionC = choiceC
        optionD = choiceD
        correctAnswer = answer
 }
```

And the func to updateQuestion where I believe sh*t is supposed to happen but doesn't.

```
func updateQuestion() {

if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1  {

imageView.image = UIImage(named:(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionImage))
QuestionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].question
optionA.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionA, for: UIControl.State .normal)
optionB.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionB, for: UIControl.State .normal)
optionC.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionC, for: UIControl.State .normal)
optionD.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionD, for: UIControl.State .normal)
selectedAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].correctAnswer

questionNumber += 1

allQuestions.list.shuffle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be shuffling the `list` every time you call `updateQuestion` which seems to be the issue here. You are only supposed to call the `shuffle` once and iterate through the questions one by one. To fix the issue remove the shuffle from `updateQuestion` and add it in `viewDidLoad` or just call it once in `updateQuestion` based on a condition like this:

```
if questionNumber == 1 {
    allQuestions.list.shuffle()
}
```